# How to remove and install new version of Easyeda in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center

I have problem with easy **[Easyeda](https://easyeda.com)** like when i open it only show white screen like this:

[image]

So i like to install new version of **Easyeda** by this command, and i like to remove it, so i tried :

```
so@so-notebook:~$ sudo easyeda
[sudo] password for so: 
sudo: easyeda: command not found
so@so-notebook:~$ sudo easyeda
sudo: easyeda: command not found
so@so-notebook:~$ sudo apt-get purge easyeda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package easyeda
```

ant is is now in **software center** and **synaptic** app like this:

[image]

So like to know i must delete it from where?

**Update:**

I downloaded the file and found the readme.txt give me the installation and uninstallation instruction like this.:

```
Install:

1.Excute the Terminal at the decompress folder, normally hotkey CTRL+ALT+T. 
You don't need to decompress the easyeda-linux-x64.zip file.

2.Input a command at the terminal
sudo bash install.sh

3.Enter, and input the login password of your operation system, enter.

4.Waiting for installing finish. After finish, you can find it on your system


Uninstall：

1.Input a command at the terminal
sudo bash uninstall.sh

2.Enter, and input the login password of your operation system, enter.

3.Waiting for uninstalling finish.



----------------- update record -------------

v2.0.0

First release
```

so it is worked like this form me:
[image]
but i like to know if i don't how this file, and don't know where it it's location of main downloaded zip file, how can uninstall it?

Thanks.

Comment: i have installed it by the file installation read-me added to question.

Comment: The zipfile you downloaded from the EasyEDA website includes complete uninstall instructions, and an uninstall script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that it was not downloaded.

So we need to download the installer:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/easyeda
cd ~/Downloads/easyeda
wget https://image.easyeda.com/files/easyeda-linux-x64-6.4.20.6.zip
```

Extract it:

```
unzip easyeda-linux-x64-6.4.20.6.zip
```

as the result you will get installation instruction as a text file:

> ```
> $ unzip easyeda-linux-x64-6.4.20.6.zip
> Archive:  easyeda-linux-x64-6.4.20.6.zip
> extracting: easyeda-linux-x64.zip   
>  inflating: How to install and uninstall.txt  
>  inflating: install.sh              
>  inflating: uninstall.sh
> ```

To install use:

```
sudo bash install.sh
```

To uninstall use:

```
cd ~/Downloads/easyeda
sudo bash uninstall.sh
```

As far as I can understand this application in 95% a web-browser to the website, so your problem may be a networking issue.

Comment: if we don't know the installation file or any source of the app, can we remove it, by some ways like finding the bash commands of app in task manager and then !?